# First Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

all

I was given a problem, it has been worded as follows: Use the substitution $ z=\frac{y}{x} $ to transform the differential equation $ \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3xy}{y^2-3x^2} $, into a linear equation. Hence obtain the general solution of the original equation.

Workings: $$ \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3(\frac{y}{x})}{(\frac{y}{x})^2-3}$$ Multiplied by $\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3z}{z^2-3} $$

$z' = \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}$

$$ (z'+\frac{y}{x^2})x = \frac{-3z}{z^2-3} $$ After a whole page of workings, I arrive at this $$z' +  \frac{z}{x} = \frac{3}{z} $$

Technically, this is a linear equation since it takes the form $y'+p(x)y = f(x)$. Since $z=f(y,x)$. However, I'm unable to compute this, since I won't know how to integrate $z$ with respect to $x$. I do know this can easily be done by separating variables, however, we are basically told to solve it this way.

Comment: "Technically, this is a linear equation": not at all, because of the $z$ on the right.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Unless, I'm misunderstanding something a linear equation takes the form: $y'+p(x)y = f(x)$ right? The equation I've provided takes the same form since $z=f(x,y(x))$ and since we have $\frac{3}{f(x,y(x))}=g(x)$. Where $g(x)$ is just an arbitrary function. I'm not trying to be confrontational, I'm just asking if this is the case and if not, why?

Comment: $3/z$ is not of the form $g(x)$, is it ?

Comment: but z is a function of x?

Comment: Sure. But $z$ is an *unknown* function of $x$. How could you integrate it ?

Comment: Exactly, you cannot. So, was this question worded incorrectly then?

Comment: If you faithfully reproduced, the question is indeed incorrect. The proposed change of variable doesn't linearize the equation.

Comment: See my update, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

From $y=zx$, draw

$$y'=z'x+z.$$

Then

$$z'x+z=-\frac{3z}{z^2-3}$$  which is separable:

$$z'x=-z-\frac{3z}{z^2-3}=-\frac{z^3}{z^2-3}.$$

> $$\log z+\dfrac3{2z^2}=C-\log x\text{, then }\log y+\dfrac{3x^3}{y^2}=C.$$

---

**Update**:

The equation can be seen as linear (and homogeneous) by swapping the roles of the dependent and independent variables and rewriting

$$\frac{dx}{dz}+\frac{z^2-3}{z^3}x=0.$$

This doesn't ease the solution.

Comment: I'm usually contempt with your replies, but you didn't actually fully read my question...

Comment: @dfdffsdfsdfsdfsdfsf: right, I didn't notice the last remark. But did you see my comment ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$y=ux$$ then we have $$u'x+u=-\frac{3u}{u^2-3}$$ simplifying we get
$$u'x=-u\left(\frac{3}{u^2-3}+1\right)$$ or
$$u'x=-\frac{u^3}{u^2-3}$$
this equation is separble and it follows
$$-\frac{u^2-3}{u^3}du=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Didn't read the whole question again...